# How to programmatically dump Launch Services database?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, osx-snow-leopard, core-foundation

How can I programmatically dump/query Launch Services database in MacOS (i.e. analog of command lsregister -dump)?

EDIT: I want to get set of associations **UTI -> Bundle_IDs**. Using ***LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType*** - does not always work, [**here**](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2010/Oct/msg00900.html) a similar trouble, therefore concluded that the best working method - parsing the output of "*lsregister -dump*", but the location of lsregister changes from version to version.

Comment: Query what?  What do you want to know?  There are some Launch Services APIs.

Comment: I need to get set of associations: uti -> bundle_id

Comment: @ProfX Did you ever end up figuring this out?

Comment: @Alexander, to be honest I don't remember whether or not I finally managed to solve this problem :)